# How to change address of parameter within a C function?

Tags: c++, c

In C++, I can do this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    void ChangeAddress(char *&para)
    {
         char *temp = "123456";
         para = temp;
    }

    int main()
    {
    char *para = "abcdef";
    ChangeAddress(para);
    printf("%s\n",para);//123456
    return 0;
    }
```

So is there any alternative way in C?

Comment: You are not changing the address of the parameter there.

Answer (score 10):

Replace reference with pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void ChangeAddress(char ** para)
{
     char *temp = "123456";
     *para = temp;
}

int main()
{
char *para = "abcdef";
ChangeAddress(&para);
printf("%s\n",para);//123456
return 0;
}
```